# Update query for database in PHP not working

Tags: php, html, sql, database, sql-update

I am having trouble updating my database data. I put the data that I want to update but when I click on the "Update" button it does
nothing. I have called the file on another php file by using `<a href="updateinfo.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Update </a>`

It also shows this error

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: fname in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\project\change1.php** on line **71**

Can someone help me figure this issue, please?

```
 <?php include("config.php"); ?>
    <?php


        if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

            $update = true;
            $record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id='".$_GET['edit']."'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($record,MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $addr = $_POST['addr'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        $id=$_GET['edit'];

        $query = "UPDATE employee SET fname='".$fname."',lname='".$lname."',password='".$password."',addr='".$addr."',phone='".$phone."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("problem inserting new record into database");
        if($result){
        header('location: show_db.php');
        }
        else {echo "Update not successful"; }
        }



    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>    
        <title>Update Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>


        <a href="show_db.php">Home</a>
        <br/><br/>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

        Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname ; ?>">
        Surname:<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">
        Password:<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
        Address:<input type="text" name="addr" value="<?php echo $addr; ?>">
        Contact:<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to enclose your inputs with `form` tags. You'll wanna set the method to `POST`. Read the intro into forms [from w3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

Comment: Misses the <form> tag that encloses your input collection

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the html inputs inside a form

```
  <form name ="form1" method ="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

            Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname ; ?>">
            Surname:<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">
            Password:<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            Address:<input type="text" name="addr" value="<?php echo $addr; ?>">
            Contact:<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help